# How to get result with keyword highlights

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 2 document types say cinema and movie.

In cinema has properties : name, cinema_uid

In movie has properties: cinema_uid, movie_name, movie_category

I can have queries says: 
please find out the cinema name which has movie named Gravity (keyword entered: Gravity) , or
please find out the cinema name which has fiction movie (keyword entered: fiction)

right now I can search through movie documents to look for the matched cinema_uid and to search again in cinema documents by filtered with the matched cinema_uid in order to get the matched cinema name.

But I have problem to highlight the matched keyword. Because the highlights comes when search through movie documents and I am not sure how can I get the result to include cinema name together with the highlight result which this case keyword gravity or fiction should return in highlights, anyway to achieve this?

Comment: How does your highlight look like?

Comment: thanks for the response, if you are refer to the configuration, currently it configured this way

 "highlight": {
    "pre_tags": [
      "<span class='highlighter'>"
    ],
    "post_tags": [
      "<\/span>"
    ],
    "fields": {
      "data_*": {
        "require_field_match": false,
        "fragment_size": 150,
        "number_of_fragments": 3
      }
    }
  }

Comment: the data_* wildcard is to allow search through all fields in the document type for this case will be movie

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking to store a field to keep both movie_name and movie_category in cinema document type in order to save the request trip and able to highlight the matched keyword with my cinema's name returned in same response. Any better solution around is most welcome